# how to add no days to date object not calendar object

Tags: android

I have a `Date` object. Now I want to add days to that `Date` object.
So how that can be done? Actually using Calendar object that can be done I know.
But in my case, I haven't used a calendar objects. Instead only used date object.

For Example, suppose I have a date object

```
Date dtStartDate=o.getStartDate();

int x=28;
```

Now what I want to do is to add 28 to this date object, means if the `dtStartDate` is 1 July 2011 
then after adding 28, `dtStartDate` will be 29 July 2011.
Please suggest it to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add Day using below

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

Here 1 is number of Day you can add.

**OR**

```
Date dtStartDate=o.getStartDate();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(dtStartDate);
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);  // number of days to add
String dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
Toast.makeText(this, "" + dt, 5000).show();
```

May be your problem solved.

Comment: but here i am not using any calender object..so how that can be done using date object

Comment: hey Nik any idea regarding adding of days in date object

Comment: you can up Arrow in answer so upvote it. like your question display 1 vote.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the equivilent number of milliseconds to the time retrieved from Date, e.g.:

```
long millis = dtStartDate.getTime();
millis = millis + x*24*60*60*1000;
Date dtEndDate = new Date();
dtEndDate.setTime(millis);
```

Comment: what is x here..is the value i want to add

Comment: but when i do that its gives me wrong result..meanns suppose my dtStartDate is 1-july-2011 and then when apply this code and at end i find that dtEnddate is 9-june-2011..how this happen..in general it should be 29-july-2011

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in two simple ways my friend. First one is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

and the second one is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
```

I think you would like to find this thing. Though there are so many persons are there who choose the first method.
Thanks.